# Implement datetime module in Python OOP

Tags: python

I am trying to implement datetime module to my Clock OOP, but the data is not being updated with the current hour, minute and second. Please have a look at the code. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```
import datetime
import time

# Python class to emulate CLock

class ClockNow2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.theHour = 0
        self.theMinute = 0
        self.theSecond = 0
        self.theLocale ="Unknow"
        self.AM = True

        #setters and getters (transformers and accessors)
        #one setter and getter for each attribute

    def setHour(self):
        self.theHour =datetime.timezone
    def getHour(self):
        return self.theHour


    def setMinute(self):
        self.theMinute = now.minute
    def getMinute(self):
        return self.theMinute


    def setSecond(self):
        self.theSecond = now.second
    def getSecond(self):
        return self.theSecond

    def setLocale(self,newval):
        self.theLocale = newval
    def getLocale(self):
        return self.theLocale

    def toString(self):
        clockstring = "The time in " +self.theLocale + " is " +str(self.theHour) \
            + ":" +str(self.theMinute) + ":" + str(self.theSecond)
        return clockstring
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include how the code is being used?  Please try to include a [minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it will make helping you much easier.

Comment: To add to @Mr.Llama's point, where is the object being updated? Is there a loop or timer or something?

Comment: `#one setter and getter for each attribute` I assume this is from some class. You should know, however, that one does not write getters and setters in Python. Python approaches encapsulations using descriptors/`property`